# Loop error with Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite

I need help with Apache2 mod_rewrite. Below is my .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag display_startup_errors on
Options -Indexes
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
```

In php code I use this:

```
header('Location: /404', true, 404);
```

When I write URLs like this:

```
https://localhost/somecontroller
```

PHP function:

```
public function run() {
    $URL = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (@$URL[1]) {
        //Create controllers name from url(Controller + Name);
        $controllerName = 'Controller' . ucfirst($URL[1], 1); //strtoupper(substr($URL[1], 0, 1)) . substr($URL[1], 1);
    } else {
        $controllerName = 'ControllerIndex';
    }

    if (@$URL[2]) {
        //Create actions name from url(action + Name)
        $actionName = 'action' . ucfirst($URL[1], 1);
    } else {
        $actionName = 'actionDefault';
    }

    if (@$URL[3]) {
        $param = $URL[3];
    }
    $Controller = new $controllerName(/*$this->DB*/);
    if (method_exists($Controller, $actionName)) {
        if (@$param) {
            if (@$param == '') {
                header('Location: /404', true, 404);
                exit();
            } else {
                @$Controller->$actionName($this->DB, $param);
            }
        } else {
            @$Controller->$actionName($this->DB);
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: /404', true, 404);
        exit();
    }
}
```

I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: It would help if you'd include your *full* PHP code and not just a single line.

Comment: You can't send a `Location:` header and a 404 status in the same request, the browser will only see the 404 and won't treat it as a redirect. (Although I don't think this is the cause of your redirect loop.) Do you always get this error, or do some URLs work OK?

Comment: @w3dk If I use header('Location: /404'); - I get same error. If I turn off rewrite rules in .htaccess - all work without errors, but mod_rewrite don't work.
When I write https://localhost - all work clearly, without any error, but when I write this: https://localhost/some - I get error.

Comment: "If I use `header('Location: /404');` - I get same error." - well, that _would_ indeed result in a redirect loop (assuming `/404` does not actually exist as a file on the filesystem or resolve using your controller). But `header('Location: /404', true, 404);` should not - although maybe that depends on the user-agent - what browser(s) are you testing on? However, `header('Location: /404', true, 404);` is not the correct way to serve a 404 anyway, try `header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found',true,404);` instead.

Comment: @w3dk
/404 - is a just name of controller, if user write uncorrect URL with nonexisting controller, script wil redirect to localhost/404. /404 is exist, it show page with custom 404 error:). Mod_rewrite is not correct work. Maybe, I'm not configured correctly Apache2? I don't know, how to fix that problem.

Comment: @w3dk
I think I understand what the problem is. It is a real manual loop:) Thank's a lot)